# R shiny dygraph causing error when deploying?

Tags: r, shiny, r-dygraphs

I have recently changed my plot to a dygraph and even though everything works fine when I run the app locally, I get the error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "config_url", value = "https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/application/") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

when I deploy the app... Here is my code

UI

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Portfolio Analysis Tool"),
    br(),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                inputId =  "DateFrom", 
                label = "Starting Year (YYYY-01-01)", 
                choices = (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1):2014    
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId =  "DateTo", 
                label = "Ending Year (YYYY-12-31)", 
                choices = (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1):2014    
            ),
            h3("Initial Portfolio"),
            p("Select a portfolio of Stocks, ETFs and/or Mutual funds trading in the same country", style = "font-size: 11px"),
            textInput("Stock","Ticker"),
            numericInput("Shares","Number of Shares",0, min = 0, step = 1),
            column(12,
                  splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                        actionButton("action", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                        actionButton("reset", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
            br(),
            br(),
            h3("Rebalancing"),
            dateInput("DateReb", "Date of Purchase/Sale", min = "2014-01-01", max = paste0(as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1, "-12-31")),
            textInput("Stock1", "Ticker"),
            numericInput("Shares1","Number of Shares (+/-)", 0, step = 1),
            column(12,
                   splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                               actionButton("action1", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                               actionButton("reset1", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
            br(),
            br(),
            fluidRow(
                align = "center",
                p("____________________________________"),
                p("Ready to launch?", style = "font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold"),
                actionButton("Go", "Go!", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")),
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            column(10,
                   splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                        htmlOutput("InitialHoldings", style = "font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline"),
                        htmlOutput("Rebalancing", style = "font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline"))),
            br(),
            br(),
            fluidRow(
                column(12,
                    align = "center",
                    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("40%", "60%"),
                    tableOutput("table"), 
                    tableOutput("tableREB"), 
                    style = "height:185px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #f7f7f7;text-align: left; overflow-x: hidden"))),
            fluidRow(
                column(12,
                   align = "center",
                   br(),
                   dygraphOutput("Graph"),
                   br(),
                   div(tableOutput("RetTable"), style = "font-size: 12px"),
                   div(tableOutput("AB"), style = "font-size: 12px")))
       )
    )
))
```

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)                            
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(plyr)
library(dygraphs)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  #Store Initial Tickers/Number of Shares from User Inputs (In Vectors and Data frame)
  valuesDF <- reactiveValues() 
  valuesDF$df <- data.frame("Stock" = numeric(0), "Shares" = numeric(0)) #Data frame 
  valuesVEC <- reactiveValues(tickers = NULL, SharesVec = NULL) #Vectors
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    isolate(valuesDF$df[nrow(valuesDF$df) + 1,] <- c(input$Stock, input$Shares)) #Data frame
    valuesVEC$tickers <- c(valuesVEC$tickers,input$Stock)                        #Vectors
    valuesVEC$SharesVec <- c(valuesVEC$SharesVec,input$Shares)
  })
  
  #Reset Initial Values and Data frame
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    valuesVEC$tickers <- valuesVEC$tickers[-1:-(length(valuesVEC$tickers))]
    valuesVEC$SharesVec <- valuesVEC$SharesVec[-1:-(length(valuesVEC$SharesVec))]
    valuesDF$df <- valuesDF$df[0,]
  })
  
  #Store Rebalancing (Data frame and vectors)
  valuesREB <- reactiveValues()
  valuesREB$REB <- data.frame("Stock" = numeric(0), "Shares" = numeric(0), "Date" = numeric(0)) 
  valuesRV <- reactiveValues(tickersREB = NULL, SharesVecREB = NULL, DateREB = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    isolate(valuesREB$REB[nrow(valuesREB$REB) + 1,] <- c(input$Stock1, input$Shares1, as.character(input$DateReb))) 
    valuesRV$tickersREB <- c(valuesRV$tickersREB,input$Stock1)                        
    valuesRV$SharesVecREB <- c(valuesRV$SharesVecREB,input$Shares1)
    valuesRV$DateREB <- c(valuesRV$DateREB,as.character(input$DateReb))
  })
  
  #Reset Rebalancing
  observeEvent(input$reset1, {
    valuesREB$REB <- valuesREB$REB[0,]
    valuesRV$tickersREB <- valuesRV$tickersREB[-1:-(length(valuesRV$tickersREB))]
    valuesRV$SharesVecREB <- valuesRV$SharesVecREB[-1:-(length(valuesRV$SharesVecREB))]
    valuesRV$DateREB <- valuesRV$DateREB[-1:-(length(valuesRV$DateREB))]
  })
  
  #Call Function
  OP <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$Go, {
    showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL))
    OP$LIST <- RunPlot(valuesVEC$tickers,valuesVEC$SharesVec,
                       as.Date(paste0(as.numeric(input$DateFrom)-1,"-12-31")),
                       as.Date(paste0(as.numeric(input$DateTo),"-12-31")),
                       valuesRV$tickersREB,valuesRV$SharesVecREB,valuesRV$DateREB)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  #For Outputs
  output$table <- renderTable({valuesDF$df})
  output$tableREB <- renderTable({valuesREB$REB})
  output$InitialHoldings <- renderText({paste("Initial Holdings")})
  output$Rebalancing <- renderText({paste("Rebalancing")})
  
  output$Graph <- renderDygraph({
    OP$LIST[[1]]
  })
  output$RetTable <- renderTable({
    OP$LIST[[2]]}, rownames = TRUE
  )
  output$AB <- renderTable({
    OP$LIST[[3]]
  })
  
  #Define Analysis functions 
  RunPlot <- function(tickers, sharesVec, FromDate, ToDate, tickersREB, SharesVecREB, DateREB){
    
    PortfolioPrices <- NULL 
    for (i in tickers){
      PortfolioPrices <- cbind(PortfolioPrices, 
                               getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = FromDate, to = ToDate,             
                                                auto.assign = F)[,6])  
    }  
    
    for (j in 1:ncol(PortfolioPrices)){   
      
      if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[1,j]) == TRUE){
        NEWFROM <- FromDate-4
        TOFROM <- ToDate-1
        TempData <- getSymbols.yahoo(tickers[j], from = NEWFROM, to = TOFROM,             
                                     auto.assign = F)[,6]
        PortfolioPrices[1,j] <- TempData[nrow(TempData),1]
        
        for (i in 1:nrow(PortfolioPrices)){
          if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[i,j]) == TRUE){
            PortfolioPrices[i,j] <- PortfolioPrices[i-1,j]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    TempValue <- PortfolioPrices[1,]
    MarketValue <- sharesVec*TempValue
    Weights <- MarketValue/sum(MarketValue) 
    
    #### REBALANCING START ###
    
    if (length(tickersREB)>0){
      
      #Initialize 
      TEMPDF <- data.frame(tickersREB, SharesVecREB, DateREB)
      WeightREB <- fortify.zoo(Weights)
      
      for (i in tickersREB){
        PortfolioPrices <- cbind(PortfolioPrices, 
                                 getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = FromDate, to = ToDate,             
                                                  auto.assign = F)[,6])  
        
        for (j in 1:nrow(TEMPDF)){
          if (TEMPDF[j,1]==i){
            DateUsed <- TEMPDF[j,3]
            SharesUsed <- TEMPDF[j,2]
          }
        }
        
        TempValue <- PortfolioPrices[DateUsed]
        sharesVec <- c(sharesVec,SharesUsed)
        MarketValue <- sharesVec*TempValue
        TempWeights <- MarketValue/sum(MarketValue) 
        
        TempWeights <- fortify.zoo(TempWeights) 
        WeightREB <- rbind.fill(WeightREB, TempWeights) 
        
      }
      
      WeightREB[is.na(WeightREB)] <- 0
      TimeXTS <- WeightREB[,1]
      WeightsXTS <- WeightREB[,2:ncol(WeightREB)]
      WeightREB <- xts(WeightsXTS,TimeXTS)
      
      Weights <- WeightREB
    }
    
    for (j in 1:ncol(PortfolioPrices)){   
      
      if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[1,j]) == TRUE){
        NEWFROM <- FromDate-4
        TOFROM <- ToDate-1
        TempData <- getSymbols.yahoo(tickers[j], from = NEWFROM, to = TOFROM,             
                                     auto.assign = F)[,6]
        PortfolioPrices[1,j] <- TempData[nrow(TempData),1]
        
        for (i in 1:nrow(PortfolioPrices)){
          if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[i,j]) == TRUE){
            PortfolioPrices[i,j] <- PortfolioPrices[i-1,j]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    ### REBALANCING END ###
    
    Rf <- getQuote("^TNX", src = "yahoo")[1,2]/100
    AssetsReturns <- na.omit(ROC(PortfolioPrices, type = "discrete"))                                  
    PortfolioReturns <- Return.portfolio(AssetsReturns, weights = Weights)                             
    PortfolioAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(PortfolioReturns, scale = nrow(PortfolioReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(PortfolioReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))                       
    colnames(PortfolioAnnualizedReturns) <- "Portfolio"
    
    SP500 <- getSymbols.yahoo("SPY", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]       
    SP500Returns <- na.omit(ROC(SP500, type = "discrete"))                                             
    SP500AnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(SP500Returns, scale = nrow(SP500Returns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(SP500Returns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))))) 
    colnames(SP500AnnualizedReturns) <- "S&P500"
    
    SPTSX <- getSymbols.yahoo("XIC.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    SPTSXReturns <- na.omit(ROC(SPTSX, type = "discrete"))                                             
    SPTSXAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(SPTSXReturns, scale = nrow(SPTSXReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(SPTSXReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))  
    colnames(SPTSXAnnualizedReturns) <- "S&P/TSX"
    
    MSCIIMI <- getSymbols.yahoo("XEF.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    MSCIIMIReturns <- na.omit(ROC(MSCIIMI, type = "discrete"))                                             
    MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(MSCIIMIReturns, scale = nrow(MSCIIMIReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(MSCIIMIReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))))) 
    colnames(MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns) <- "MSCI EAFE IMI"
    
    MSCIEME <- getSymbols.yahoo("XEC.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    MSCIEMEReturns <- na.omit(ROC(MSCIEME, type = "discrete"))                                             
    MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(MSCIEMEReturns, scale = nrow(MSCIEMEReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(MSCIEMEReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))  
    colnames(MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns) <- "MSCI Emerging Markets"
    
    PortfolioCumReturns <- fortify.zoo(PortfolioReturns+1)                                             
    SP500CumReturns <- fortify.zoo(SP500Returns+1)
    SPTSXCumReturns <- fortify.zoo(SPTSXReturns+1)
    MSCIIMICumReturns <- fortify.zoo(MSCIIMIReturns+1)
    MSCIEMECumReturns <- fortify.zoo(MSCIEMEReturns+1)
    
    for (j in 2:nrow(PortfolioCumReturns)){                                                            
      PortfolioCumReturns[j,2] <- PortfolioCumReturns[j-1,2]*PortfolioCumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(SP500CumReturns)){
      SP500CumReturns[j,2] <- SP500CumReturns[j-1,2]*SP500CumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(SPTSXCumReturns)){
      SPTSXCumReturns[j,2] <- SPTSXCumReturns[j-1,2]*SPTSXCumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(MSCIIMICumReturns)){
      MSCIIMICumReturns[j,2] <- MSCIIMICumReturns[j-1,2]*MSCIIMICumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(MSCIEMECumReturns)){
      MSCIEMECumReturns[j,2] <- MSCIEMECumReturns[j-1,2]*MSCIEMECumReturns[j,2]
    }
    
    PortfolioCumReturns <- PortfolioCumReturns - 1                                                      
    SP500CumReturns <- SP500CumReturns - 1
    SPTSXCumReturns <- SPTSXCumReturns - 1
    MSCIIMICumReturns <- MSCIIMICumReturns - 1
    MSCIEMECumReturns <- MSCIEMECumReturns - 1
    
    ReturnsTABLE <- cbind(PortfolioAnnualizedReturns,SP500AnnualizedReturns,SPTSXAnnualizedReturns,MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns,MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns)
    
    Benchmark <- getSymbols.yahoo("^GSPC", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    BenchmarkReturns <- na.omit(ROC(Benchmark, type = "discrete"))  
    BETA <- CAPM.beta(PortfolioReturns, BenchmarkReturns, Rf/(nrow(BenchmarkReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))
    ALPHA <- CAPM.jensenAlpha(PortfolioReturns, BenchmarkReturns, Rf/(nrow(BenchmarkReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))
    df <- data.frame(ALPHA,BETA)
    
    #Interactive Plot
    #Portfolio
    PCR1 <- PortfolioCumReturns[,1]
    PCR2 <- PortfolioCumReturns[,2]
    PortfolioCumReturns <- xts(PCR2,PCR1)
    colnames(PortfolioCumReturns) <- "Portfolio"
    
    #S&P500
    SP1 <- SP500CumReturns[,1]
    SP2 <- SP500CumReturns[,2]
    SP500CumReturns <- xts(SP2,SP1)
    colnames(SP500CumReturns) <- "S&P500"
    
    #S&P/TSX
    TSX1 <- SPTSXCumReturns[,1]
    TSX2 <- SPTSXCumReturns[,2]
    SPTSXCumReturns <- xts(TSX2,TSX1)
    colnames(SPTSXCumReturns) <- "S&P/TSX"
    
    #MSCI EAFE IMI
    IMI1 <- MSCIIMICumReturns[,1]
    IMI2 <- MSCIIMICumReturns[,2]
    MSCIIMICumReturns <- xts(IMI2,IMI1)
    colnames(MSCIIMICumReturns) <- "MSCI EAFE IMI"
    
    #MSCI Emerging Markets
    EME1 <- MSCIEMECumReturns[,1]
    EME2 <- MSCIEMECumReturns[,2]
    MSCIEMECumReturns <- xts(EME2,EME1)
    colnames(MSCIEMECumReturns) <- "MSCI Emerging Markets"
    
    NEW <- cbind(PortfolioCumReturns,SP500CumReturns,SPTSXCumReturns,MSCIIMICumReturns,MSCIEMECumReturns)
    
    #Hotfix bug (365TD vs 252TD)
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    
    #Delete NAs
    for (j in 1:ncol(NEW)){   
      
      for (i in 1:nrow(NEW)){
        if (is.na(NEW[i,j]) == TRUE){
          NEW[i,j] <- NEW[i-1,j]
        }
      }
    }
    
    Graph <- dygraph(NEW, ylab = "Returns",main = "Performance Overview") %>%
      dyRangeSelector() %>%
      dyOptions(colors = c("Navy","dodgerblue4","steelblue","lightblue","lightsteelblue")) %>%
      dyLegend(width = 560) 
      
    
    #Output
    return(list(Graph, ReturnsTABLE, df))
  }
  
})
```

Note that if you change the dygraph() at the very end of the function in the server by a plot(), there is no more error message.. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put everything in a single app.R file and it works fine : https://hleviel.shinyapps.io/testapp/

```r
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)                            
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(plyr)
library(dygraphs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Portfolio Analysis Tool"),
  br(),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId =  "DateFrom", 
        label = "Starting Year (YYYY-01-01)", 
        choices = (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1):2014    
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId =  "DateTo", 
        label = "Ending Year (YYYY-12-31)", 
        choices = (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1):2014    
      ),
      h3("Initial Portfolio"),
      p("Select a portfolio of Stocks, ETFs and/or Mutual funds trading in the same country", style = "font-size: 11px"),
      textInput("Stock","Ticker"),
      numericInput("Shares","Number of Shares",0, min = 0, step = 1),
      column(12,
             splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                         actionButton("action", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                                      style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                         actionButton("reset", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                                      style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
      br(),
      br(),
      h3("Rebalancing"),
      dateInput("DateReb", "Date of Purchase/Sale", min = "2014-01-01", max = paste0(as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1, "-12-31")),
      textInput("Stock1", "Ticker"),
      numericInput("Shares1","Number of Shares (+/-)", 0, step = 1),
      column(12,
             splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                         actionButton("action1", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                                      style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                         actionButton("reset1", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                                      style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
      br(),
      br(),
      fluidRow(
        align = "center",
        p("____________________________________"),
        p("Ready to launch?", style = "font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold"),
        actionButton("Go", "Go!", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      column(10,
             splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                         htmlOutput("InitialHoldings", style = "font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline"),
                         htmlOutput("Rebalancing", style = "font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline"))),
      br(),
      br(),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               align = "center",
               splitLayout(cellWidths = c("40%", "60%"),
                           tableOutput("table"), 
                           tableOutput("tableREB"), 
                           style = "height:185px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #f7f7f7;text-align: left; overflow-x: hidden"))),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               align = "center",
               br(),
               dygraphOutput("Graph"),
               br(),
               div(tableOutput("RetTable"), style = "font-size: 12px"),
               div(tableOutput("AB"), style = "font-size: 12px")))
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  #Store Initial Tickers/Number of Shares from User Inputs (In Vectors and Data frame)
  valuesDF <- reactiveValues() 
  valuesDF$df <- data.frame("Stock" = numeric(0), "Shares" = numeric(0)) #Data frame 
  valuesVEC <- reactiveValues(tickers = NULL, SharesVec = NULL) #Vectors
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    isolate(valuesDF$df[nrow(valuesDF$df) + 1,] <- c(input$Stock, input$Shares)) #Data frame
    valuesVEC$tickers <- c(valuesVEC$tickers,input$Stock)                        #Vectors
    valuesVEC$SharesVec <- c(valuesVEC$SharesVec,input$Shares)
  })
  
  #Reset Initial Values and Data frame
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    valuesVEC$tickers <- valuesVEC$tickers[-1:-(length(valuesVEC$tickers))]
    valuesVEC$SharesVec <- valuesVEC$SharesVec[-1:-(length(valuesVEC$SharesVec))]
    valuesDF$df <- valuesDF$df[0,]
  })
  
  #Store Rebalancing (Data frame and vectors)
  valuesREB <- reactiveValues()
  valuesREB$REB <- data.frame("Stock" = numeric(0), "Shares" = numeric(0), "Date" = numeric(0)) 
  valuesRV <- reactiveValues(tickersREB = NULL, SharesVecREB = NULL, DateREB = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    isolate(valuesREB$REB[nrow(valuesREB$REB) + 1,] <- c(input$Stock1, input$Shares1, as.character(input$DateReb))) 
    valuesRV$tickersREB <- c(valuesRV$tickersREB,input$Stock1)                        
    valuesRV$SharesVecREB <- c(valuesRV$SharesVecREB,input$Shares1)
    valuesRV$DateREB <- c(valuesRV$DateREB,as.character(input$DateReb))
  })
  
  #Reset Rebalancing
  observeEvent(input$reset1, {
    valuesREB$REB <- valuesREB$REB[0,]
    valuesRV$tickersREB <- valuesRV$tickersREB[-1:-(length(valuesRV$tickersREB))]
    valuesRV$SharesVecREB <- valuesRV$SharesVecREB[-1:-(length(valuesRV$SharesVecREB))]
    valuesRV$DateREB <- valuesRV$DateREB[-1:-(length(valuesRV$DateREB))]
  })
  
  #Call Function
  OP <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$Go, {
    showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL))
    OP$LIST <- RunPlot(valuesVEC$tickers,valuesVEC$SharesVec,
                       as.Date(paste0(as.numeric(input$DateFrom)-1,"-12-31")),
                       as.Date(paste0(as.numeric(input$DateTo),"-12-31")),
                       valuesRV$tickersREB,valuesRV$SharesVecREB,valuesRV$DateREB)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  #For Outputs
  output$table <- renderTable({valuesDF$df})
  output$tableREB <- renderTable({valuesREB$REB})
  output$InitialHoldings <- renderText({paste("Initial Holdings")})
  output$Rebalancing <- renderText({paste("Rebalancing")})
  
  output$Graph <- renderDygraph({
    OP$LIST[[1]]
  })
  output$RetTable <- renderTable({
    OP$LIST[[2]]}, rownames = TRUE
  )
  output$AB <- renderTable({
    OP$LIST[[3]]
  })
  
  #Define Analysis functions 
  RunPlot <- function(tickers, sharesVec, FromDate, ToDate, tickersREB, SharesVecREB, DateREB){
    
    PortfolioPrices <- NULL 
    for (i in tickers){
      PortfolioPrices <- cbind(PortfolioPrices, 
                               getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = FromDate, to = ToDate,             
                                                auto.assign = F)[,6])  
    }  
    
    for (j in 1:ncol(PortfolioPrices)){   
      
      if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[1,j]) == TRUE){
        NEWFROM <- FromDate-4
        TOFROM <- ToDate-1
        TempData <- getSymbols.yahoo(tickers[j], from = NEWFROM, to = TOFROM,             
                                     auto.assign = F)[,6]
        PortfolioPrices[1,j] <- TempData[nrow(TempData),1]
        
        for (i in 1:nrow(PortfolioPrices)){
          if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[i,j]) == TRUE){
            PortfolioPrices[i,j] <- PortfolioPrices[i-1,j]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    TempValue <- PortfolioPrices[1,]
    MarketValue <- sharesVec*TempValue
    Weights <- MarketValue/sum(MarketValue) 
    
    #### REBALANCING START ###
    
    if (length(tickersREB)>0){
      
      #Initialize 
      TEMPDF <- data.frame(tickersREB, SharesVecREB, DateREB)
      WeightREB <- fortify.zoo(Weights)
      
      for (i in tickersREB){
        PortfolioPrices <- cbind(PortfolioPrices, 
                                 getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = FromDate, to = ToDate,             
                                                  auto.assign = F)[,6])  
        
        for (j in 1:nrow(TEMPDF)){
          if (TEMPDF[j,1]==i){
            DateUsed <- TEMPDF[j,3]
            SharesUsed <- TEMPDF[j,2]
          }
        }
        
        TempValue <- PortfolioPrices[DateUsed]
        sharesVec <- c(sharesVec,SharesUsed)
        MarketValue <- sharesVec*TempValue
        TempWeights <- MarketValue/sum(MarketValue) 
        
        TempWeights <- fortify.zoo(TempWeights) 
        WeightREB <- rbind.fill(WeightREB, TempWeights) 
        
      }
      
      WeightREB[is.na(WeightREB)] <- 0
      TimeXTS <- WeightREB[,1]
      WeightsXTS <- WeightREB[,2:ncol(WeightREB)]
      WeightREB <- xts(WeightsXTS,TimeXTS)
      
      Weights <- WeightREB
    }
    
    for (j in 1:ncol(PortfolioPrices)){   
      
      if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[1,j]) == TRUE){
        NEWFROM <- FromDate-4
        TOFROM <- ToDate-1
        TempData <- getSymbols.yahoo(tickers[j], from = NEWFROM, to = TOFROM,             
                                     auto.assign = F)[,6]
        PortfolioPrices[1,j] <- TempData[nrow(TempData),1]
        
        for (i in 1:nrow(PortfolioPrices)){
          if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[i,j]) == TRUE){
            PortfolioPrices[i,j] <- PortfolioPrices[i-1,j]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    ### REBALANCING END ###
    
    Rf <- getQuote("^TNX", src = "yahoo")[1,2]/100
    AssetsReturns <- na.omit(ROC(PortfolioPrices, type = "discrete"))                                  
    PortfolioReturns <- Return.portfolio(AssetsReturns, weights = Weights)                             
    PortfolioAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(PortfolioReturns, scale = nrow(PortfolioReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(PortfolioReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))                       
    colnames(PortfolioAnnualizedReturns) <- "Portfolio"
    
    SP500 <- getSymbols.yahoo("SPY", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]       
    SP500Returns <- na.omit(ROC(SP500, type = "discrete"))                                             
    SP500AnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(SP500Returns, scale = nrow(SP500Returns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(SP500Returns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))))) 
    colnames(SP500AnnualizedReturns) <- "S&P500"
    
    SPTSX <- getSymbols.yahoo("XIC.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    SPTSXReturns <- na.omit(ROC(SPTSX, type = "discrete"))                                             
    SPTSXAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(SPTSXReturns, scale = nrow(SPTSXReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(SPTSXReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))  
    colnames(SPTSXAnnualizedReturns) <- "S&P/TSX"
    
    MSCIIMI <- getSymbols.yahoo("XEF.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    MSCIIMIReturns <- na.omit(ROC(MSCIIMI, type = "discrete"))                                             
    MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(MSCIIMIReturns, scale = nrow(MSCIIMIReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(MSCIIMIReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))))) 
    colnames(MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns) <- "MSCI EAFE IMI"
    
    MSCIEME <- getSymbols.yahoo("XEC.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    MSCIEMEReturns <- na.omit(ROC(MSCIEME, type = "discrete"))                                             
    MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(MSCIEMEReturns, scale = nrow(MSCIEMEReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y'))), Rf = Rf/(nrow(MSCIEMEReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))  
    colnames(MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns) <- "MSCI Emerging Markets"
    
    PortfolioCumReturns <- fortify.zoo(PortfolioReturns+1)                                             
    SP500CumReturns <- fortify.zoo(SP500Returns+1)
    SPTSXCumReturns <- fortify.zoo(SPTSXReturns+1)
    MSCIIMICumReturns <- fortify.zoo(MSCIIMIReturns+1)
    MSCIEMECumReturns <- fortify.zoo(MSCIEMEReturns+1)
    
    for (j in 2:nrow(PortfolioCumReturns)){                                                            
      PortfolioCumReturns[j,2] <- PortfolioCumReturns[j-1,2]*PortfolioCumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(SP500CumReturns)){
      SP500CumReturns[j,2] <- SP500CumReturns[j-1,2]*SP500CumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(SPTSXCumReturns)){
      SPTSXCumReturns[j,2] <- SPTSXCumReturns[j-1,2]*SPTSXCumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(MSCIIMICumReturns)){
      MSCIIMICumReturns[j,2] <- MSCIIMICumReturns[j-1,2]*MSCIIMICumReturns[j,2]
    }
    for (j in 2:nrow(MSCIEMECumReturns)){
      MSCIEMECumReturns[j,2] <- MSCIEMECumReturns[j-1,2]*MSCIEMECumReturns[j,2]
    }
    
    PortfolioCumReturns <- PortfolioCumReturns - 1                                                      
    SP500CumReturns <- SP500CumReturns - 1
    SPTSXCumReturns <- SPTSXCumReturns - 1
    MSCIIMICumReturns <- MSCIIMICumReturns - 1
    MSCIEMECumReturns <- MSCIEMECumReturns - 1
    
    ReturnsTABLE <- cbind(PortfolioAnnualizedReturns,SP500AnnualizedReturns,SPTSXAnnualizedReturns,MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns,MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns)
    
    Benchmark <- getSymbols.yahoo("^GSPC", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
    BenchmarkReturns <- na.omit(ROC(Benchmark, type = "discrete"))  
    BETA <- CAPM.beta(PortfolioReturns, BenchmarkReturns, Rf/(nrow(BenchmarkReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))
    ALPHA <- CAPM.jensenAlpha(PortfolioReturns, BenchmarkReturns, Rf/(nrow(BenchmarkReturns)/(as.numeric(format(ToDate,'%Y')) - as.numeric(format(FromDate,'%Y')))))
    df <- data.frame(ALPHA,BETA)
    
    #Interactive Plot
    #Portfolio
    PCR1 <- PortfolioCumReturns[,1]
    PCR2 <- PortfolioCumReturns[,2]
    PortfolioCumReturns <- xts(PCR2,PCR1)
    colnames(PortfolioCumReturns) <- "Portfolio"
    
    #S&P500
    SP1 <- SP500CumReturns[,1]
    SP2 <- SP500CumReturns[,2]
    SP500CumReturns <- xts(SP2,SP1)
    colnames(SP500CumReturns) <- "S&P500"
    
    #S&P/TSX
    TSX1 <- SPTSXCumReturns[,1]
    TSX2 <- SPTSXCumReturns[,2]
    SPTSXCumReturns <- xts(TSX2,TSX1)
    colnames(SPTSXCumReturns) <- "S&P/TSX"
    
    #MSCI EAFE IMI
    IMI1 <- MSCIIMICumReturns[,1]
    IMI2 <- MSCIIMICumReturns[,2]
    MSCIIMICumReturns <- xts(IMI2,IMI1)
    colnames(MSCIIMICumReturns) <- "MSCI EAFE IMI"
    
    #MSCI Emerging Markets
    EME1 <- MSCIEMECumReturns[,1]
    EME2 <- MSCIEMECumReturns[,2]
    MSCIEMECumReturns <- xts(EME2,EME1)
    colnames(MSCIEMECumReturns) <- "MSCI Emerging Markets"
    
    NEW <- cbind(PortfolioCumReturns,SP500CumReturns,SPTSXCumReturns,MSCIIMICumReturns,MSCIEMECumReturns)
    
    #Hotfix bug (365TD vs 252TD)
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    if (is.na(NEW[1,2]) == TRUE){
      NEW <- NEW[-1,]
    }
    
    #Delete NAs
    for (j in 1:ncol(NEW)){   
      
      for (i in 1:nrow(NEW)){
        if (is.na(NEW[i,j]) == TRUE){
          NEW[i,j] <- NEW[i-1,j]
        }
      }
    }
    
    Graph <- dygraph(NEW, ylab = "Returns",main = "Performance Overview") %>%
      dyRangeSelector() %>%
      dyOptions(colors = c("Navy","dodgerblue4","steelblue","lightblue","lightsteelblue")) %>%
      dyLegend(width = 560) 
    
    
    #Output
    return(list(Graph, ReturnsTABLE, df))
  }
  
})


shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Very strange. I will give it a try thank you